# how to save an openGL texture to an array of bytes?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

On android the context could be lost when the application goes in background, so i must save the texture first and reload it after. How can i do this ?

I don't want to save it to a file (but if if possible it's a beginning for me), but i would rather prefer to save it to an array of "bytes"

Right now i keep in memory the bits used to create the texture, but i think it's not really efficient

Comment: How do you create the texture in the first place? Is it a procedural texture? If you load it from a file, why not just reload it?

Comment: i load it from internet url and update it manually (add caption, etc..). I don't want to download it again :(